# Why does the shell output often use `mixed_characters' in its output?

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line, manpage

I see backtick ( ` ) (also called a grave accent) characters mixed with apostrophe characters ( ' ) used together in all kinds of command-line output. Surely the reason/history behind why is documented online somewhere, but I couldn't find where.

Here are a couple examples of what I'm talking about:

From the `make` man page:

> If makefile is `-', the standard input is read.

Some `rake` output:

> .../ruby_koans/koans/about_strings.rb:6:in
>   `test_double_quoted_strings_are_strings'

Why the inconsistency?

---

I suppose the broader question here is "Why not use 'proper' single or double quotation marks, as appropriate?" but I realize that the apostrophe (and the grave accent) are simply more available on "standard" U.S. keyboards. Why *that* is, though...)

Comment: The apostrophe is really the only single quote mark in ASCII. In a some typewriter fonts, though, the apostrophe tilts to the right so typists sometimes used the grave accent and single quote/apostrophe to "dress things up" and make it look a wee bit more like typeset text - kind of silly, if you ask me. As to why the same character isn't used at both ends in this case? I assume it is to give a clue that the outermost quotes are not part of the quoted material (which may itself be a quoted string of some kind). Or, maybe whoever established the standard was just one of those silly typists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This had already been asked and [answered on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75349/why-do-nix-y-folks-single-quote-like-this-instead-of-like-this) (now deleted). The top answer was a best guess that it came from LaTeX.

A similar question has also been [answered on SE English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17695/any-reference-on-the-usage-of-a-backtick-and-single-quotation-mark-like-this). The top answer was that it was to work around limited character sets, which lacked separate characters for ‘this style of quotation marks’.

Comment: The question on Programmers seems to have been deleted.